# What is the relation between Lie algebra/ group and formal group laws

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, formal-groups

$\text{Relation between Lie algebra/ group and formal group laws:}$

I have found a sentence within a short article but could not grasp its meaning fully. The sentence (exactly copied) is the following one-

$\textit{Lie algebras are to smooth groups over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ as formal group laws}$ $\textit{ are to smooth algebraic groups over any ring $\Bbb R$.}$

Can you please explain the essence of this sentence ?